# How to give unique usernames from a list of usernames to the users in the firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to give unique usernames to my users from the list of usernames that I have created. But I am not getting the logic of what should be done. I have tried uploading that as a JSON file in the Firebase realtime database but as every name is unique how to call it so that it will be assigned to the user

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of assigning a unique name to a user anywhere in Firebase, so anything you do will be specific to our app and use-case.

But a common approach would be to associate the [UID of the Firebase Authentication user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_a_users_profile) with the user name they selected. So:

```
usernames: {
  "Sahil": "uidOfSahil",
  "puf": "uidOfFrank"
}
```

You could have the unclaimed names in the same list, but have a marker value instead of the UID. For example if your marker value is `false`:

```
usernames: {
  "Abe": false,
  "James": false,
  "Sahil": "uidOfSahil",
  "Tony": false,
  "puf": "uidOfFrank"
}
```