# how to check the current Firebase data under uid?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to check uid from firebase Realtime database, but its only returns the current uid and when I try to check uid with previous uid then also it only returns the current uid. I had tried many ways and searched but I can't get the exact solution, please if any one could help.

here what I am using to check the uid

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

here is my code how I am trying to check

```
 String userEnteredUserName = binding.textLoginUserName.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
 String userEnteredPassword = binding.textPassword.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    Query checkUser = reference.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).orderByChild("userName").equalTo(userEnteredUserName);
    Log.d("uids", "uid: " + uid);
    checkUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            binding.textLoginUserName.setError(null);
            binding.textLoginUserName.setErrorEnabled(false);
            Log.d("users", "Username: " + snapshot.toString());

            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                String passwordFromDB = snapshot.child(userEnteredUserName).child("password").getValue(String.class);
                if (passwordFromDB.equals(userEnteredPassword)) {
      //next activity
}else{
Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

In log what I get,

```
2022-02-06 13:13:06.173 18093-18093/abc C/uids: uid: OFtpR6bfISP3Odd9K1oGWCQmeEf2
```

Here is my firebase data, "aisha12" is working which is under the current uid but when I try to check "vgbb" it returns only the current uid
[image]

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: yes, whenever I check userName, using this "FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()".my code only checks username only under this uid "OFtpR6bfISP3Odd9K1oGWCQmeEf2" and when I try to check  another username under this uid as example, "3l6RIm1ACacB4WOEiq5k7nrIk8b2" but it only checks under this "OFtpR6bfISP3Odd9K1oGWCQmeEf2". The problem is that I want to check different different  username under different uid.  can you please help me out.@Alex Mamo

Comment: what is the code you tried for getting the value of other users

Comment: this is the code "  Query checkUser = reference.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).orderByChild("userName").equalTo(userEnteredUserName);"  @ 
Sambhav Khandelwal

Comment: When using `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()` you are getting the UID, not the user, right? So what exactly would you like to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to allow a user to register a username and ensuring that the username is unique. Your current data structure doesn't allow you to do that query though.

Firebase Realtime Database can only order/filter on a value that is at a fixed path under each child node of the location you query. So in your current code:

```
reference.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).orderByChild("userName").equalTo(userEnteredUserName);
```

You are querying the direct child nodes of `/Users/$uid` looking for the username under there. Since you're specifying the UID in that path, you're only searching under that specific user.

There is no way with your current data structure to search across all `/Users`, since the property you are looking for is under `/Users/$uid/$username/userName`, so with *two* dynamic keys in there, and the database can only handle one dynamic key.

---

To allow the query, you will need to change the data structure and remove the `$userName` level from it, so that you get:

```
Users: {
  "3l6Rm....": {
    "userName": "vgbb",
    ...
  },
  "OftpR...": {
    "userName": "aisha12",
    ...
  }
}
```

Now you can search for the username with:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

Query checkUser = reference.orderByChild("userName").equalTo(userEnteredUserName);
```

I also recommend checking out these previous questions on allowing a user to register a unique username:

- [How do you prevent duplicate user properties in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294478/how-do-you-prevent-duplicate-user-properties-in-firebase/25328654#25328654)
- [Firebase security rules to check unique value of a child #AskFirebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39149216/firebase-security-rules-to-check-unique-value-of-a-child-askfirebase)
- [How to check if usernames are unique in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57616310/how-to-check-if-usernames-are-unique-in-firebase/57616541#57616541)
- [unique property in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41443767/unique-property-in-firebase/41446816#41446816)
- [How to give unique usernames from a list of usernames to the users in the firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53985066/how-to-give-unique-usernames-from-a-list-of-usernames-to-the-users-in-the-fireba/53985131#53985131)
- [Check value already exists or not in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63861763/check-value-already-exists-or-not-in-firebase/63862082#63862082)

Comment: thank you for the explanation @Frank van Puffelen
but I have one question that can I check User name under uid
Users: {
$uid:{
userName:.........
}
}

Comment: Once you had modified the data structure as shown in my answer, that's what the `Query checkUser = reference.orderByChild("userName").equalTo(userEnteredUserName);` in my answer does.